# Surface area of a spherical dish

Tags: integration, area, spheres

How do I calculate the surface area of a spherical dish with a radius of curvature of 265 meters and a diameter of 305 meters? We can't use the normal formula 4(pi)r^2 because the sphere isn't a full or exactly half. How would you do it?

Comment: By "spherical dish" you mean the shape you would get by plane cutting a hollow sphere across one of its great circles?

Comment: @Frpzzd I think they mean they've cut a sphere of radius $265$ along a line of latitude such that the resulting shape has a diameter of $305$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: that's right @kccu

Comment: @Helena Do you know about surface integrals and spherical coordinates?

Comment: I know for the volume I'd use volume of revolution, but how would I find the surface area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the figure below, I've cut a sphere of radius $265$ along a latitude to obtain a spherical bowl of diameter $305$ (I'm just showing a cross-section). We can see a right triangle with hypotenuse $265$, and side opposite angle $\phi$ of length $152.5$. Then we can find $\phi = \arcsin\left(\frac{152.5}{265}\right) \approx 0.613 \text{ rad}$.

If you are familiar with surface integrals and spherical coordinates, the surface area of the bowl can now be computed as the integral of $1$ over the region $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0 \leq \phi \leq \arcsin\left(\frac{152.5}{265}\right)$, $\rho = 265$.

[image]

If you've been studying solids of revolution, then maybe you are familiar with the surface area formula $\int_a^b 2\pi x \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \ dx$ for the surface obtained by rotation $y=f(x)$, $a \leq x \leq b$, about the $y$-axis. The right half of the cross section of the bowl below is described by $f(x)=\sqrt{265^2-x^2}$, $0 \leq x \leq 152.5$ (assuming we center the sphere at the origin). So
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{2}(265^2-x^2)^{-1/2}\cdot -2x = \frac{x}{\sqrt{265^2-x^2}}$$
and
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} = \sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{265^2-x^2}}\right)^2}= \sqrt{1+ \frac{x^2}{265^2-x^2}}=\frac{265}{\sqrt{265^2-x^2}}.$$
So we end up with
$$\int_0^{152.5}2\pi x\frac{265}{\sqrt{265^2-x^2}} \ dx$$
which can be solved by $u$-substitution with $u=265^2-x^2$.

This page might be useful to you: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SurfaceArea.aspx

Comment: Thankyou so much, this makes sense. I was just searching on wikipedia and it gave the formula as 2 π r h, is the the same or different?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#cite_note-handbook-1

Comment: That is what you should get. Note that you are not given $h$, but you could find it given the radius of the sphere and the diameter of the spherical cap.

Comment: Yep I just tried and found it to be 24.23 meters. So would doing solids of revolution and using the 2 π r h formula give me the same answer?

Comment: Any correct method will give you the same answer.

Comment: I got 80383.752 as the answer with the solids of revolution method but got 40349.00792 with the formula. I can't figure out what i did wrong... What is the answer supposed to be?

Comment: What did you use for the radius and height in the formula from wikipedia? The radius should be the radius of the *sphere*, not the spherical cap.

Comment: I used 265 for the radius, it should be right. I used 24.23... for height, which i found using pythag.

Comment: The height is wrong. The vertical side of the right triangle in my figure has length $x$ where $x^2+15.25^2=265^2$. The height of the spherical cap is then $h=265-x$. I got $80383.752$ using the formula from Wikipedia, so I think your solid of revolution answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I entered 285 instead of 265 in my calculator. Now I got the right answer. Thanks!!!